# Error al insertar un dato en una columna recién añadida

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo el siguiente problema resulta que tengo una tabla a la cual le agregue un campo, ahora le hago un Update para cambiar los registros Null ya que al agregar la columna nueva sale por defecto con ese valor, pero al ejecutar el query sale el error `campo no es valido`. En realidad desconozco que pueda estar pasando ya verifique nombre de la columna este bien escrito y nada, espero me puedan ayudar.

utilizo SQL SERVER.

update a la columna nueva `REM_hnddom`

```
UPDATE REMUNERACION
SET REM_hnddom=200
WHERE EMP_codigo=10101 AND PER_periodo='202102'
```

script de la tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REMUNERACION](
    [EMP_codigo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PER_periodo] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [REM_dias_trabajo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REM_minutos_tardanza] [int] NULL,
    [REM_minutos_permiso] [int] NULL,
    [REM_basico_bruto] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_familiar] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [REM_hnd] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_hnn] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_hed25] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_hen25] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_hed35] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_hen35] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_bonificacion_noct] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_dominical] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_reintegro_afecto] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [REM_reintegro_haber_reclamo] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [REM_comisiones] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_feriado] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_subsidio] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_descanso_medico] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_viaticos] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_subtotal_afecto]  AS ((((((((((((((([REM_familiar]+[REM_hnd])+[REM_hnn])+[REM_hed25])+[REM_hen25])+[REM_hed35])+[REM_hen35])+[REM_bonificacion_noct])+[REM_dominical])+[REM_reintegro_afecto])+[REM_reintegro_haber_reclamo])+[REM_comisiones])+[REM_feriado])+[REM_subsidio])+[REM_descanso_medico])+[REM_viaticos]),
    [REM_movilidad] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [REM_vales_alimento] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_reintegro_inafecto] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [REM_alimentacion] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_canasta_navidad] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [REM_subtotal_inafecto]  AS (((([REM_movilidad]+[REM_vales_alimento])+[REM_reintegro_inafecto])+[REM_alimentacion])+[REM_canasta_navidad]),
    [REM_contrato] [int] NULL,
    [REM_estado] [char](1) NULL,
    [REM_comentario] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [REM_razon_social] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [REM_hnddom] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [XPKREMUNERACION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EMP_codigo] ASC,
    [PER_periodo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMUNERACION]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [R_27] FOREIGN KEY([PER_periodo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PERIODO] ([PER_periodo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMUNERACION] CHECK CONSTRAINT [R_27]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMUNERACION]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [R_4] FOREIGN KEY([EMP_codigo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EMPLEADO] ([EMP_codigo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REMUNERACION] CHECK CONSTRAINT [R_4]
GO
```

Error mostrado:

```
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
Mens. 207, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
El nombre de columna 'REM_hnddom' no es válido.
```

Comment: emmm puedes agregar la query que estás usando?, y el script de la tabla?

Comment: Cuál tabla, cuál campo, cuál update, cuáles registros? Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade la información relevante. Ya hiciste el recorrido, así que debes estar más familiarizado con la forma de usar le sitio. Eso incliye un ejemplo mínimo verificable y, además, no usar mayúsculas sostenidas. Por favor, evítalo

Comment: acabo de editar la publicación, a la espera de sus comentarios

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error completo? Agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta. En el script de la tabla ya está la columna... lo generaste desde tu cliente SQL? Cómo añadiste la columna? Qué versión de SQL Server usas?

Comment: Lo añadí mediante el diseñador, genere el script de la tabla después que agregue el campo. Así es lo genere desde mi cliente SQL

Comment: Tendras mas de una base con todas las tablas y estaras ejecutando en el lugar equivocado? si haces un select * a esa tabla, sale el campo que vos queres?

Comment: Ya verifique eso y si estoy consultando la BD correcta, si cuando le hago un select a la tabla si me sale el campo nuevo

Answer (score 0):

El problema fue con un trigger que tenia esa tabla la cual no dejaba actualizar, se tuvo que actualizar el trigger para poder realizar los insert. Disculpen la demora de la respuesta pero lo publico por si alguno se le presenta en algún momento.